# Seeking a 3 variable function with a specific property

Tags: functions, special-functions

I'm looking for a function $f(x_1,x_2,y)$ which has the following property.

$y \in [0,1]$, $x_1,x_2>0$.

The minimum value of $f(x_1,x_2,y)$ is 
$max(x_1,x_2)$ at $y=1$;

The maximum value of $f(x_1,x_2,y)$ is at $x_1+x_2$ at $y=0$;

The function should preferably use only math operations,(not functions like max,min,abs).

One example would be (using max and min) will be):

$f(x_1,x_2,y)=max(x_1,x_2)+(1-y)*min(x_1,x_2)$

Comment: Powers are considered a math operation.

Comment: Why do you have this requirement of avoiding "comparison" functions ?

Comment: I am using this in an objective function inside the summation for an NLP. The analysis becomes easier with trivial mathematical functions.Basically the "if then else" functions are more algorithm oriented

Comment: Then I strongly suggest that you decompose your domain in two half spaces, $x_1<x_2$ and $x_1>x_2$ if you can, so that you can work with two nice functions, $x_2+(1-y)x_1$ and $x_1+(1-y)x_2$. (Solutions with powers will give you headaches.)

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what i do in the (algorithmic) solution I've in place now. "Sorting" the list of x's(x1,x2,x3....) and then processing them. I wanted to see if I can find a better "algorithm" with this formulation avoiding the sort altogether. Sorry if I sound a little cryptic here. I hope you understand my intention.

Comment: If you just need the maximum, non need to sort, a linear search suffices. If your intent is to optimize an algorithm for speed, you can post a question a such.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more complicated function which is $max(x_1,x_2)$ at $y=0$ and $x_1+x_2$ at $y=1$: 
$$(x_1^{1/y}+x_2^{1/y})^y$$

Answer (score 0):

For $x_1,x_2>0$ one can prove that
$$\max(x_1,x_2)=\frac{x_1+x_2+\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2}}{2}\quad\text{and}\quad\min(x_1,x_2)=\frac{x_1+x_2-\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2}}{2}$$
Hence we can take a function such as
$$f(x_1,x_2,y)=\frac{(2-y)(x_1+x_2)+y\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2}}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that computing the function $\max$ with a finite number of the four basic operations is possible.

As in the post by @MarioG, if the square root is allowed, you can obtain the absolute value from $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$, and the absolute value gives you access to the maximum with $\max(x_1,x_2)=\frac12(x_1+x_2+|x_1-x_2|)$.

---

The $\max$ function is piecewise linear and has singularities along the line $x_1=x_2$ where the derivatives are discontinuous.

On the other hand, the only functions that you can build out of $+-\times\div$ are the so-called rational fractions, i.e. the ratio of two polynomials. Such functions are smooth, with possible asymptotes, but they are unable to produce discontinuities in the derivative where they take finite values.

Allowing the powers opens more possibilities, as these can introduce discontinuities.